# calling .map on the first X elements of an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to call .map on only the first X elements of an array. How do I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In ruby 1.9

```
array.first(X).map{|e| ...}
```

In ruby 1.8

```
array[0, X].map{|e| ...}
```

Answer (score -3):

Simple,

```
array.first(X-number)
```

and that's all.

See you...